# UAP app crashes when page navigating backwards to page with MapControl

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-rt

I have a MapControl on my MainPage with ItemsSource binded to a ObservableCollection (via x:Bind). When I navigate to another page and then back again, the app crashes randomly (about every 5th time) and without any hint what the problem might be.

I have found a workaround with setting the ObservableCollection to null when navigating from my MainPage and set it back to the backed up value when navigating back to it. But as this is a very unpleasant workaround I am wondering what the reason for the crash could be...

My app is a Universal Windows 10 app. Crash appears mobile as well as desktop.

Comment: I sometimes also experienced the crash when resizing the windows with the MapControl visible

Comment: a little code please!

Comment: I have a page with a map control that I can navigate from and to on uwa 10 and I don't have any problem .. we need some code .

Comment: I agree ! did you find any solution?

Comment: I worked around by setting the ItemsSource, the MapControl is binding to  null and refreshed all bindings in OnNavigatedFrom. After navigating back, I am setting the ItemsSource back the the (previously cashed) value and again, refresh all bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a memory leak. You can run diagnostic in visual studio and see it. In map_unload event you can set to null your collection and iterate for Map.Children and set each element to null (Map.Children.ToArray()[i] = null). Maybe it will help you.